# Test numpy array against specific values in an if sentence

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)`. I would like to return something for values in the array between *a* and *b*, and then something else between the other values.

I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
if 2 <= x < 7:
    return x**2
else:
    return x**3
```

I got an error message: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

However those two functions test against the whole array and return all the elements. I also tried with `np.where()` and `np.logical_and()` function and got the same error.

Comment: `a<x<b` only works for scalar values, not arrays. It doesn't have any per-element behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
np.where((x>=2)&(x<7), x**2, x**3)
```

is what you are looking for.

`np.where` takes (up to) 3 arguments. A condition (so an array of booleans), and 2 values to pick up from depending on the condition.

Note that there are 3 problems in your code.

1. You can't `if x<7` if x is a numpy array. `x<7` is an array of booleans. And and array of booleans is neither true nor false. This is what means the error message you got.
2. Syntax `2<=x<7` is not possible with arrays. `2<=x` is an array of booleans. `x<7` is another array of boolans. You can `and` two arrays of booleans with operator `&`. But `2<=x<7` is not an array of booleans. For in reality the same reason: `2<=x<7` is a python short cut for `(2<=x) and (x<7)`. Which makes sense if x is a scalar, and therefore `2<=x` and `x<7` are both booleans (or anything with a "truth value"). But not if `2<=x` and `x<7` are arrays (hence the reason there is another operator, &, for such things)
3. Even if it were working, even if `if 2<=x<7:...` made sense, what would you do from there. It is a single return. And this is not quantum mechanics: either the outcome is `return x**2` or it is `return x**3`. Can't be both. So the logic cannot work anyway. It cannot be that simple. What you want to return is neither `x**2` nor `x**3` but a new array made of both.

Well, I say "it cannot be that simple", but as you see, the correct answer is very simple too. But it relies on numpy function, not on pure python `if/else`.

## Another method

It is not the only numpy way.

For example you could also do

```py
ret=np.empty_like(x)
cond=(x>=2)&(x<7)
ret[cond]=x[cond]**2
ret[~cont]=x[~cond]**2
return ret
```

One advantage of that method is that it doesn't compute `x**2` and `x**3` everywhere, even where it isn't need (while the `np.where` one does compute `**2` and `**3` of all number, and the select one of the 2 for each case).

The drawback is that it does that with several indexing operation. And in this very case since the indexing operation is not really less expansive than `**2` or `**3`, it is not faster. In this example, whatever the size of x, the `np.where` method is 30% faster on my machine, even tho it does useless computations.

But on a more complicated case, for example, say

```py
def whereBased(x):
    return np.where((x>=2)&(x<7), np.sin(2*np.sqrt(np.exp(x))*np.pi), np.cos(2*np.sqrt(np.exp(x))*np.pi))
```

so a case where the operation is a bit more costful than just `**2`, then it is worth trying to avoid computing both sin and cos on all `x` and drop half of those computations.

```py
def indexBased(x):
    ret=np.empty_like(x)
    cond=(x>=2)&(x<7)
    ret[cond] = np.sin(2*np.sqrt(np.exp(x[cond]))*np.pi)
    ret[~cond] = np.cos(2*np.sqrt(np.exp(x[~cond]))*np.pi)
    return ret
```

This time, it is the opposite. The index based solution is 30% faster.

And that is still a very simple case (just 2 multiplications, a sin/cos, an exp and a sqrt per number).

The more complex is you actual computation (I take that your real use case is not `x**2` vs `x**3`) the more worthy is this solution that does only the needed computations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what about if I am computing something with a lot more lines inside a condition? Your solutions were only for one-liners. 
For example, I want to compute something for x < 0 and something else for x > 0, and code for each computation is about 50 lines?

Comment: @Murg It doesn't really change anything to both of my answer. Only, it won't be one-liner. But for `np.where`, you can `case1=...50lines...`, `case2=...50lines...` `return np.where((x>=2)&(x<7), case1, case2)`. For second method, likewise: `cond=(x>=2)&(x<7)` `x1=x[cond]`, `x2=x[~cond]`, `res=np.empty_like(x)`, `res[cond]=...50lines using x1...`, `res[~cond]=...50lines using x2...`

Comment: For example, using only 2 lines, if you want to compute `y=x+1`, `return y**2` for case `x>0`, and `y=-x-2` `return y**3` for case `x<0` (sure, you could do this in 1 line but let's say you can't since I can't really fit a bigger example, especially in comments). With `np.where` you would `y=x+1; res1=y**2`, `y=-x-2; res2=y**3`, `return np.where(x>0, res1, res2)`.

Comment: With second method, you would do like this: `cond=x>0` `x1=x[cond]` `x2=x[~cond]`, `res=np.empty_like(x)`, `y=x1+1` `res[cond]=y**2`, `y=-x2-2`, `res[~cond]=y**3`

Comment: Note that I forgot (your new condition of `x>0` made me think of that only now) another important reason why second method might be preferable. Let say for example that you want to return √x is x>0, else 0 (a quite realistic example, I think). Returning `np.where(x>0, np.sqrt(x), 0)` would work. But with a complaint about numerical error (computing sqrt of negative values, since that is what sqrt would do). Numerical error that has no impact, since we just ignore the result of cases where there is an error (since error occur when `x<0` and we keep result of `sqrt` only when `x>0`.

Comment: But still, that warning is not very aesthetic. Plus for some other more convoluted examples, it might even be a fatal error, not just some warning (for example, if the values are used as index for a lookup table; or some iterative process take an infinite amount of time if x<0). So, in short, sometimes, it is not just optimization consideration that makes you not want to compute `then` result when condition is not fulfilled. Sometimes it is because you really can't.

Comment: So, that is one extra reason to prefer the `res[cond]=fthen(x[cond]); res[~cond]=felse(x[~cond])` method. Even if it is less spectacular as one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison `2 <= x < 7` is not valid. You are comparing `NumPy` array here, not discrete value.

You could be using the `NumPy` `where` method instead:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)

result = np.where((2 <= x) & (x < 7), x**2, x**3)
```

which outputs:

```
array([   0.,    1.,    4.,    9.,   16.,   25.,   36.,  343.,  512.,
        729., 1000.])
```